# Search query using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to LINQ and I'm trying to search for a result by the event name or event date in ASP.NET MVC Application.

Below is my code:

```
public ActionResult search(string name, string date)
{
    Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

    List<Event> e = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventName.Contains(name) || x.Date.Contains(date)).ToList();

    return View(e);
}
```

My search.cshtml file basically has two input fields for event name (this is the first field) and event date (second field), and a submit button.

When I search with a part of certain event date, it returns correct result. However, it returns random results that do not contain the particular search string.

I also tried the following code:

```
List<Event> e = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventName == name || x.Date == date).ToList();
```

In this case also, events with the search string returned no result.
Can someone help me figure out how I can make this search work?

Comment: You should be using `DateTime` rather than `string` to compare dates.

Comment: What is the datatype of date on your DB?

Comment: The data type is varchar in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

> When I search with a part of certain event date, it returns correct result. However, it returns random results that do not contain the particular search string.

So you want the result to match the date AND the search string?
Then you should use the AND operator (&& instead of ||) like this:

```
List<Event> e = db.Events.Where(x => x.EventName.Contains(name) && x.Date.Contains(date)).ToList();
```

Comment: I would like to search for an event that matches either the name or the date.

Comment: Then what you have seems correct. But what exactly is going wrong is unclear from your question and the code you provided. Please provide more info.